# BigQuery: Invalid Date, Error running query

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get all the purchase date data from a table but it spits out an error because there's an invalid date on the table. I have tried looking around for similar problems, but the problem I have seems to be a bit different. My problem is there is a date where the year value is invalid, it's: 650-01-22

> Error running query
> Invalid date: '650-01-22'; while executing the filter on column 'output.purchase_date.value'; Column 'request_id'

I have tried putting a filter to only produce data over a certain date, casting it into a string, safe casting, re-parsing the date format, but I keep encountering the same error

```
SELECT purchase_date FROM MyTable WHERE purchase_date >= "2020-08-10"
```

Any idea if this is possible without messing with the table directly? Is it possible to just filter them out? Thank you!

Comment: is `purchase_date` a date type column? if it is string try to `where length(purchase_date) = 10` or cast as string before and then filter your date

Comment: @luisvenezian yes it's a date type column. I have tried casting it into a string first as I've mentioned on my post, but the error message would still pop up

Comment: does your table is external? is it querying a google cloud storage? saying it because i can't reproduce that with simple create table ddl then following inserts

Comment: @luisvenezian, may be converting date to string and then applying your string length based filter will also work right? As we are changing the datatype on the fly and still leaving the result as expected. Just asking. So, the filter will be something like length(cast(purchase_date to string)) == 10 in the where clause.

Comment: @luisvenezian yes the table is in google cloud storage. are you saying you are unable to reproduce the error after deliberately inserting the same invalid date?

Comment: @AishwaryShukla I have tried casting the purchase date into string to try the same thing, but as I have mentioned on my post, the error message would pop up if I try to cast (or safe cast) it into string; or parsing it. It seems like any kind of function I try to use would result in the same error message.

Comment: @AishwaryShukla yes you got the idea! but in the case of external tables like Ozys I would recommend to try alter table schema for reading that column as string

Comment: @luisvenezian hmm so it seems like the only workaround is to alter the table directly? I doubt they'd want to change the column type to string but I will keep it in mind. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date_type) date type is valid from 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31, my test showed that date should be `0650-01-22` with the left missed zero instead of `650-01-22`. Apparently there is no way for query that date column without a hand for ajustments in your data.